# Is there an algorithm for the Rubik's 360?

Tags: strategy, algorithm, twisty-puzzles

Is there an algorithm to help me solve the [Rubik's 360](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubik%27s_360)?

[image: Image of Rubik's 360]

Usually I just do it at random, but I rarely succeed.

Comment: I don't know if this is the case for all of them, but mine slightly catches in a certain position, allowing me to get the first hole to the bottom and get a ball into it. After that though, I just throw it around and hope to get lucky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the balls to the ball layer so they can be dropped to the outer pockets, you need to flip the inner ball so the counterweight is pointing up after which it catches and will only rotate one way. This can be done by quickly rotating the entire ball around. I do this by quickly rotating the ball from where the black is horizontal to where the are vertical around 270° around 2 of the pockets.

You'll know that it catches when the hole and counterweight of middle ball are horizontal when the black knobs are vertical.

Then guide one of the lower color balls into the hole and gently let it line up with the closest hole. Which will put it in the correct layer. After that it is easy to drop that ball into the correct pocket. Remember to not turn it around or you will lose the ball again.

Answer (score 0):

## The hack

Throw the ball up, put some spin on it, wait for the ball to peel to second layer, and if the ball lands in the wrong side, release it.

Source: personal experience